# TCPClient : Custom timeout time

Tags: delphi, tcpclient

I need to set custom timeout for `TTcpClient`. I think the default timeout time is about 20-25 seconds but I need to change it to 500ms. Is it possible And How?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     TcpClient2.RemoteHost := '192.168.1.1';
     TcpClient2.RemotePort := '23';
     TcpClient2.Connect;

     tcpclient2.Receiveln();
     tcpclient2.Sendln('admin');
     tcpclient2.Receiveln;
   end;
```

I tried `non-blocking` option but the software returns an error after I click on button And I have to do it again 4-5 times. Any help?

Thanks :)

Comment: The [`TTcpClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Web.Win.Sockets.TTcpClient) class doesn't belong to Indy.

Comment: @TLama Yes sorry edited

Comment: Well, I would set the connection timeout socket option in the [`OnCreateHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Web.Win.Sockets.TTcpClient.OnCreateHandle) event handler. Uhm, if there would be [`such timeout option`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx)... I've said enough so let's hope someone who knows WinSock will help.

Comment: In the fact we love users who are asking a lot :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Winsock has no connect timeout, but this can be overcomed.

You have several options:

1. Without threads:

   - Using non-blocking mode: call `Connect`, then wait using [Winsock select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) function (encapsulated in [TBaseSocket Select](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Web.Win.Sockets.TBaseSocket.Select) method inherited by TTcpClient).
   - Using blocking mode: changing temporarily to non-blocking mode and proceeding as in the previous case.
2. With threads: see Remy Lebeau's answer to [How to control the connect timeout with the Winsock API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785340/859646).
3. Use Indy.

### Blocking vs non-blocking

Using blocking or non-blocking mode is a very important design decision that will affect many of your code and which you can't easily change afterward.

For example, in non-blocking mode, receive functions (as `Receiveln`), will not wait until there is enough input available and could return with an empty string. This can be an advantage if is this what you need, but you need to implement some strategy, such as waiting using `TcpClient.WaitForData` before calling the receive function (in your example, the `Receiveln-Sendln-Receiveln` will not work as is).

For simple tasks, blocking mode is easier to deal with.

### Non-blocking mode

The following function will wait until the connection is successful or the timeout elapses:

```
function WaitUntilConnected(TcpClient: TTcpClient; Timeout: Integer): Boolean;
var
  writeReady, exceptFlag: Boolean;
begin
  // Select waits until connected or timeout
  TcpClient.Select(nil, @writeReady, @exceptFlag, Timeout);
  Result := writeReady and not exceptFlag;
end;
```

How to use:

```
// TcpClient.BlockMode must be bmNonBlocking

TcpClient.Connect; // will return immediately
if WaitUntilConnected(TcpClient, 500) then begin // wait up to 500ms
  ... your code here ...
end;
```

Also be aware of the following drawbacks/flaws in TTcpClient's non-blocking mode design:

- Several functions will call `OnError` with `SocketError` set to `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` (10035).
- `Connected` property will be `false` because is assigned in `Connect`.

### Blocking mode

Connection timeout can be achieved by changing to non-blocking mode after socket is created but before calling `Connect`, and reverting back to blocking mode after calling it.

This is a bit more complicated because `TTcpClient` closes the connection and the socket if we change `BlockMode`, and also there is not direct way of creating the socket separately from connecting it.

To solve this, we need to hook after socket creation but before connection. This can be done using either the `DoCreateHandle` protected method or the `OnCreateHandle` event.

The best way is to derive a class from TTcpClient and use `DoCreateHandle`, but if for any reason you need to use TTcpClient directly without the derived class, the code can be easily rewriten using `OnCreateHandle`.

```
type
  TExtendedTcpClient = class(TTcpClient)
  private
    FIsConnected: boolean;
    FNonBlockingModeRequested, FNonBlockingModeSuccess: boolean;
  protected
    procedure Open; override;
    procedure Close; override;
    procedure DoCreateHandle; override;
    function SetBlockModeWithoutClosing(Block: Boolean): Boolean;
    function WaitUntilConnected(Timeout: Integer): Boolean;
  public
    function ConnectWithTimeout(Timeout: Integer): Boolean;
    property IsConnected: boolean read FIsConnected;
  end;

procedure TExtendedTcpClient.Open;
begin
  try
    inherited;
  finally
    FNonBlockingModeRequested := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TExtendedTcpClient.DoCreateHandle;
begin
  inherited;
  // DoCreateHandle is called after WinSock.socket and before WinSock.connect
  if FNonBlockingModeRequested then
    FNonBlockingModeSuccess := SetBlockModeWithoutClosing(false);
end;

procedure TExtendedTcpClient.Close;
begin
  FIsConnected := false;
  inherited;
end;

function TExtendedTcpClient.SetBlockModeWithoutClosing(Block: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  nonBlock: Integer;
begin
  // TTcpClient.SetBlockMode closes the connection and the socket
  nonBlock := Ord(not Block);
  Result := ErrorCheck(ioctlsocket(Handle, FIONBIO, nonBlock)) <> SOCKET_ERROR;
end;

function TExtendedTcpClient.WaitUntilConnected(Timeout: Integer): Boolean;
var
  writeReady, exceptFlag: Boolean;
begin
  // Select waits until connected or timeout
  Select(nil, @writeReady, @exceptFlag, Timeout);
  Result := writeReady and not exceptFlag;
end;

function TExtendedTcpClient.ConnectWithTimeout(Timeout: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if Connected or FIsConnected then
    Result := true
  else begin
    if BlockMode = bmNonBlocking then begin
      if Connect then // will return immediately, tipically with false
        Result := true
      else
        Result := WaitUntilConnected(Timeout);
    end
    else begin // blocking mode
      // switch to non-blocking before trying to do the real connection
      FNonBlockingModeRequested := true;
      FNonBlockingModeSuccess := false;
      try
        if Connect then // will return immediately, tipically with false
          Result := true
        else begin
          if not FNonBlockingModeSuccess then
            Result := false
          else
            Result := WaitUntilConnected(Timeout);
        end;
      finally
        if FNonBlockingModeSuccess then begin
          // revert back to blocking
          if not SetBlockModeWithoutClosing(true) then begin
            // undesirable state => abort connection
            Close;
            Result := false;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  FIsConnected := Result;
end;
```

How to use:

```
TcpClient := TExtendedTcpClient.Create(nil);
try
  TcpClient.BlockMode := bmBlocking; // can also be bmNonBlocking

  TcpClient.RemoteHost := 'www.google.com';
  TcpClient.RemotePort := '80';

  if TcpClient.ConnectWithTimeout(500) then begin // wait up to 500ms
    ... your code here ...
  end;
finally
  TcpClient.Free;
end;
```

As noted before, `Connected` doesn't work well with non-blocking sockets, so I added a new `IsConnected` property to overcome this (only works when connecting with `ConnectWithTimeout`).

Both `ConnectWithTimeout` and `IsConnected` will work with both blocking and non-blocking sockets.